# Como evitar o envio de requisições PHP seguidas?

Tags: php, envio-de-email, email, formulário, phpmailer

Bom, a situação é a seguinte existem alguns formulários em meu website. Esses formulários estão programados para disparar e-mails, utilizando a classe PHPMailer. O que acontece é o seguinte, se a pagina demora um pouco para responder o usuário fica clicando muitas vezes no botão enviar, o que gera vários disparos de e-mails duplicados. Existe uma maneira de evitar que ocorra tantas requisições?

Comment: sim, você pode simplesmente bloquear o botão logo apos o usuário clicar nele, bloquear que eu falo é dar um `disable`

Comment: Apesar desta ser sobre email, e a outra sobre inserção de DB, a grande maioria das respostas da outra tem solução que serve para qualquer envio repetido, em especial o redirect (e o PHPMailer não tem relação nenhuma com o problema, apesar de estar nas tags).

Answer (score 7):

Você pode usar JavaScript para desabilitar o botão
assim que seja clicado uma vez,
assim o usuário não poderá fazer várias requisições
se estiver com JavaScript ativado,
o que é o caso da maioria,
mas ai depende do tipo de usuários do seu sistema:

Exemplo de botão de `submit` que se desabilita sozinho:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Enviando…'; this.form.submit();" value="Enviar">
```

### [Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hJtA/)

Comment: Vale a pena também adicionar em alguma parte do layout um aviso do tipo: 'Aguarde alguns instantes, seu email já está sendo enviado!' =)

Comment: O problema é que se validarmos de alguma forma o formulario, o botao vai ficar desabilitado...

Comment: Você pode fazer uma função em JS para validar seu formulário e coloca-la no evento onsubmit deste. Nesta função você aproveita para verificar o(s) campo(s) e, de acordo com a necessidade, habilitar ou desabilitar o botão...

Comment: @CesarAndré, "se validarmos de alguma forma" já é [*uma outra pergunta*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) ;) Muito elegante a solução, Miguel! Um detalhe, precisei incluir um `form.submit()` pro envio do formulário poder funcionar: **`onclick="this.disabled=true; this.value='Enviando...'; this.form.submit(); return true;"`**

Comment: @brasofilo: boa observação, vou alterar a resposta para refletir isso. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira eficiente de evitar multiplas requisições desnecessarias seguidas é utilizar um serviço de captcha, assim a requisição só é feita uma vez e depois que o usuário enviar o captcha, isso evita a multiplas requisições e também o problema de possíveis spams.

Porém captcha acaba deixando o envio do formulário mais lento para o usuário (o que é desagradavel), então uma solução que me vem em mente é a seguinte:

Você pode armazenar em uma session o tempo exato em que a ultima requisição foi feita, e estabelecer um limite minimo de tempo para realizar uma nova ação.

Você também pode desabilitar o botão de envio com o atributo `disabled` utilizando javascript, isso vai causar um efeito mais agradável embora possa ocorrer o caso de o usuário estar com o javascript desabilitado.

O script abaixo pode ajudar:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {

    $(this).find('[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

});
```